# How to configure keepalive for MSSQL client which uses SQL Server Driver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, keep-alive

I have a client application which uses SQL Server Driver to connect with a remote MSSQL Server. (Installed SQL Server 2012 in client and Server machines)

Once connection is established and if the connection is idle, i could see keepalive signals being sent by server, which is ACKed by client and sent from client, which is ACKed by server. (Using wireshark)

By default, a keepalive signal is sent every 30 seconds by server as well as client.

If i change the value of "Keep Alive" option in "SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER -> TCP/IP -> Properties" to "20000", server starts sending keepalive signals every 20 seconds.

[image]

Similar way, how do i configure the keepalive timeout value for client? 
Where the default value is set?

I tried changing "Keep Alive" option in "SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration -> Client Protocols -> TCP/IP -> Properties", but it didn't affect the client keepalive time.

Comment: Make sure you restart the server or the changes wont be applied.